# How to display _only specific_ images from SD card in a GalleryView?

Tags: android, android-sdcard, galleryview

Following the guide at http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.com/2009/09/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html, how can I show only image files following a pattern [EDIT] **in a Gallery widget** [/EDIT]? I'm using a dedicated directory on the sdcard and I have to use the following filename pattern to store images:

```
/sdcard/[MYDIRECTORY]/[APPNAME]_[AN-ID]_[ANOTHER-ID]_[DATE].jpg
```

Now, I'd like to show only those pictures where *[AN-ID] == x*.

I believe that I have to manipulate the ContentResolver, but I have no idea how to do this. I know it would be much easier to just save all associated pictures in a single folder, but I'm not able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to do this modification to above link code:

---

Uri uri=Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,""+imagename);
 cursor = managedQuery( uri,
                        projection, // Which columns to return
                        null,       // Return all rows
                        null,
                        null);

Comment: Well, this only enables me to load _one_ specific image. I, however, would like to load _several_ images, according to a pattern (but not all in the folder).